# how to use InlineQueryResultsButton with express js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, telegram-api, node-telegram-bot-api

Hi I want to use InlineQueryResultsButton from Telegram api bot i cant find any solution for it
here this an api telegram for expressJs node
https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inlinequeryresultsbutton

can someone help me with it if i should make this api by myself or if you have the source please share with me

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.